# Removing string from list if string contain specified character

Tags: python, list

Having following:

```
list1 = ['something',"somet'hing",'somet"hing','some;thing','']
list2 = [';','"',"'"]
```

I would like to get filtered list1 if string inside list contain any of the character from list2 or string is blank. Desired output:

```
list3 = ['something']
```

Currently I'm doing it manually like this:

```
list1withoutEmptyLines= list(filter(None, list1))
list1withoutQuote = [x for x in list1withoutEmptyLines if "'" not in x]
list1withoutDoublequotes = [x for x in list1withoutQuote if "\"" not in x]
list1withoutSemicolon = [x for x in list1withoutDoublequotes if ";" not in x]
```

and It works perfectly fine. I also tried to automate it through creating list of forbidden characters like this:

```
forbiddenCharacters = ['"', ';', '\'']
filteredLines = []

for character in forbiddenCharacters:
    filteredLines = [x for x in uniqueLinesInFile if character not in x]
```

but list called filteredLines still contains strings with semicolon ";". Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `[x for x in list1 if not any(y in x for y in list2)]`

Comment: You are overwriting `filteredLines` in each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) combined with the built-in function [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
list1 = ['something', "somet'hing", 'somet"hing', 'some;thing', '']
list2 = [';', '"', "'"]

result = [s for s in list1 if s and not any(c in s for c in list2)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['something']
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for s in list1:
    if s and not any(c in s for c in list2):
        result.append(s)
```